# Url path in extension

Tags: extensions, url-rewrite

I recently added an extension to my store ([more precise](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/top-seller-new-feature-most-viewed-catalog-sale-recently-ordered-all-products-7-in-one-catalog-by-etatvasoft.html)) and the **url** I am getting is `www.mystore.com/catalogextensions/index/promotional/`.

Where does this url generate and how can i change it?

For example I would prefer having `www.mystore.com/sale`. I am quite new to Magento, so I apologize for this simple question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Magentos built in URL rewrite management, I don't know if it will work on that extension.

1. In the admin interface go to **Catalog->URL-Rewrite Management**
2. Click on **Add URL Rewrite**
3. Select **Custom** from the dropdown
4. In the **ID path** and **Request Path** put **sale** or whatever you want your URL to look like
5. Put the extension URL after your domain **catalogextensions/index/promotional/** into the **Target Path**
6. Select **No** for redirect

These are per store so you will have to do it for each one.